# How to properly implement a free product offering?

Tags: schema.org

If I'm listing a free online product, is there a recommended way to use the wording "Free" when structuring its price, rather than $0.00?

[schema.org/Offer specification](http://schema.org/Offer) says a string representation of a price must be of type `PriceSpecification`, I'm not sure what it means.

**Alternative #1**:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="price">Free</span>
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
</div>
```

**Alternative #2**:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <span itemprop="description">Free</span>
    <meta itemprop="price" content="0" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
</div>
```

I'm leaning toward alternative #1 (seems obvious) but I've had no luck finding a reference explicitly stating that use.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The alternative #2 is a correct way for most of semantical analysis performed by the search engines crawlers, like googlebot. With other words, Google will understand that the offer is free with the second alternative.

Comment: Can you point a reference implementing it this way so I could check?

Comment: [This post](https://plus.google.com/106943062990152739506/posts/XKZBodXtTaH), for example

Comment: ...which is inaccessible by now :(

Comment: OP here. Google does recommend approach #2 with "price: 0" as indicated here: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/product#microdata